# twitter premium Api buid a search query with colon

Tags: string, api, twitter, string-concatenation

I have a twitter premium API enabled and i am trying to get twitter data from a request query

search query rules

1. few words are in twitter body  or in hashtags
2. language japanese
3. skip retweets
4. within date range
5. and some default parameters

I don't use any twitter API client library,I have created own small library to authentication and get the results.This issue with the **search query** because i am getting twitter data for other queries as expected.

query i have tried

```
{ "query":"lang:ja(-is:retweet((Reゼロ　OR Re:ゼロ) OR (#Reゼロ　OR #Re:ゼロ) ))",
  "maxResult":500,
  "fromDate":somedate,
  "toDate":somedate
}
```

response is a error saying

> There were errors processing your request:missing EOF at '(' (at
>   position 8)

I tried these methods,did't work.

```
"lang:ja(-is:retweet((Reゼロ　OR "/Re:ゼロ/") OR (#Reゼロ　OR "/#Re:ゼロ/") ))"
"lang:ja(-is:retweet((Reゼロ　OR 'Re:ゼロ') OR (#Reゼロ　OR '#Re:ゼロ') ))"
```

as far as i understand **colon between word makes the error** ex (Re:ゼロ),because if i remove colon it is return the data for query matching. I think colon makes complicated with **twitter search operators** like is:retweet.

these are some links i have followed

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/search/guides/premium-operators
https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tutorials/translating-plain-language-to-pt-rules

how to solve this?

Comment: By reading the error message, I feel that this might be a string quoting or mismatched parenthesis problem.

What is the error message when you query `lang:ja -is:retweet ( ( "Reゼロ" OR "Re:ゼロ" ) OR ( #Reゼロ OR "#Re:ゼロ" ) )`.

Also, in what format are you sending the query data? GET request query string, POST request form data, or POST request JSON?